# How can I avoid "Callback was already called" with async.queue?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, queue, asynccallback

I'm trying to make a series of calls using async.queue, and each call has its own callback where I'm using mocha to test that an expected result was returned.

When I use a concurrency value of 1 (my NUMBER_OF_THREADS variable), this all works great.  However, when I use any value greater than 1, I get errors stating, "Error: Callback was already called."  For instance, If I send 10 messages, and set my NUMBER_OF_THREADS to 5, the first 5 messages will go smoothly, but then I start seeing the duplicate-callback errors around message 6 or 7 (see below).  Do you know how I can avoid this error?

My test file (where async queue is defined):

```
var myQueue = async.queue(function(options, callback){   
    var counter = options.counter;

    myService.sendMyMessage(options.text, counter, function(result) {
        var myText = result.content.text;
        console.log("Response " + myService.counter + ": " + myText);

        responses.push(myText);
        callback();
    });
}, NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

myQueue.drain = function(){ 
    console.log("sends completed"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSends; i++) {
        assert.equal(myExpectedResponse,responses[i],"text doesn't match");
    }
    done();
};  

for (var j = 1; j <= numberOfSends; j++) {
    var options = {
        counter: j,
        text: "Hello_" + j
    };
    myQueue.push(options);
}
```

My service file (where the sends and responses happen):

```
myService.callback = function() {};

myService.sendMyMessage = function(message, counter, myCallback) {
    console.log("Sending message " + counter + ": " + message);
    var myContent = JSON.stringify(myModel.makeMessage(message));

    myModel.post(content)
        .then(function(res) {
            myService.callback = myCallback;
        });
};

myService.otherService = function(done) {
    app = express();
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myRoute/events', function(req, res, next) {
    var response = {
        "myId": "1234567890",
        "myVersion": 1
    };

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    if (myService.callback)
    {
        myService.counter ++;

        myService.callback(req.body);
        //myService.callback = null;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('the callback is NULL');
    }
});
```

My results in the console:

```
Sending message 1: Hello_1  
Sending message 2: Hello_2
Sending message 3: Hello_3
Sending message 4: Hello_4
Sending message 5: Hello_5
Response 1: myResponse
Sending message 6: Hello_6
Response 2: myResponse
Sending message 7: Hello_7
Response 3: myResponse
Sending message 8: Hello_8
Response 4: myResponse
Sending message 9: Hello_9
Response 5: myResponse
Sending message 10: Hello_10
Response 6: myResponse
Response 7: myResponse
Error: Callback was already called.
    at myFile.js:12:34
```

If I un-comment the myService.callback = null line, the the first send of my last batch causes myService.callback to be null too early.  For example, if I send 10 requests with NUMBER_OF_THREADS=5, requests 1 thru 5 will work great.  However, once I send requests 1 thru 10, request #10 will nullify myService.callback too early.  Example responses:

```
Sending message 1: Hello_1  
Sending message 2: Hello_2
Sending message 3: Hello_3
Sending message 4: Hello_4
Sending message 5: Hello_5
Response 1: myResponse
Sending message 6: Hello_6
Response 2: myResponse
Sending message 7: Hello_7
Response 3: myResponse
Sending message 8: Hello_8
Response 4: myResponse
Sending message 9: Hello_9
Response 5: myResponse
Sending message 10: Hello_10
Response 6: myResponse
the callback is NULL
the callback is NULL
the callback is NULL
the callback is NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this now.

In my test file, I'm simply calling sendMyMessage now; I no longer expect a callback from sendMyMessage.  In drain, I wait for the total number of responses to be hit, and then loop through those responses.

```
var myQueue = async.queue(function(options, callback){   
    var counter = options.counter;

    myService.sendMyMessage(options.text, counter);
    callback();
}, NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

myQueue.drain = function(){ 
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

    if (myService.responseCounter == myNumberOfMessages) {

      clearInterval(myInterval);
      for (var i = 0; i < myNumberOfMessages; i++) {
        assert.equal(myExpectedResponse,myService.responses[i],"error");
      }
      done();
    }
  }, 5000);

};  

for (var j = 1; j <= myNumberOfMessages; j++) {
  var options = {
    counter: j,
    text: "Hello"
  };

  myQueue.push(options);
}
```

Then, in my service file, I'm now using an *array* of callbacks; I'm no longer dependent on a single callback getting set or nullified.  Each call to myModel.post defines a new element in this callbacks array.

```
myService.sendLineMessage = function(message, counter) {

myModel.post(content, sign, config, request, log, run)
    .then(function(res) {
        myService.callbacks[counter] = function(result) {
            var myText = result.content.text;
            myService.responses.push(resultText);
        };
    });
};

myService.otherService = function(done) {
    app = express();
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.post('/myRoute/events', function(req, res, next) {

    var response = {
        "myId": "1234567890",
        "myVersion": 1
    };

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response));

    myService.responseCounter++;

    if (myService.callbacks[myService.responseCounter])
    {
        myService.callbacks[myService.responseCounter](req.body);
        myService.callbacks[myService.responseCounter] = null;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('the callback is NULL');
    }
});
```